# Why do these javascript variables share scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

Since there are two separate functions involved, namely `_GetFoo` and `_CountBar` shouldn't the variable `bar` be in a different scope even though they both use it? If you copy paste this and then run it, it will display the problem with two alerts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var example = function () {

    var Foo = [];

    function _BuildFoo(size) {
        for (var buildSize = 0; buildSize < size; buildSize++) {
            Foo.push(buildSize);
        }
    }

    function _GetFoo(index) {
        for (bar in Foo) {
            //do Foo bar
        }
    }

    function _CountBar() {
        for (bar in Foo) {
         alert(bar); //bar = 0
         _GetFoo(1);
         alert(bar); //bar is incremented from _GetFoo function and is now 19
         break;
        }
    }

    return {
        _CountBar: _CountBar,
        _BuildFoo: _BuildFoo
    }
}

var foobar = new example();
foobar._BuildFoo(20);
foobar._CountBar();
</script>
```

Why do `_GetFoo` and `_CountBar` share scope?

Comment: Because without being bound to each function's scope, JS assumes that `bar` is attached to the global scope. Try `var bar; for (bar in Foo) /* ... */` instead :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the keyword `var`, `bar` becomes a global variable. You need:

```
for (var bar in Foo) {
```

or alternatively,

```
var bar;
for (bar in Foo) {
```

Answer (score 1):

They both share `example` because they both are in a function.

Also, `bar` is not declared, and JavaScript will assume it is `global`.

Answer (score 0):

No, bar is not declared as a local variable in the function scope.

But there's something worse: Never use for-in-loops for arrays!

```
var foo = [];
for (var i=0; i<foo.length; i++)
    // do something with foo[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a little the other answers, there are two ways to avoid creating global vars through functions:

- Use the `var` keyword, e.g `var foo`
- Create the variable in the function parameters, e.g `function myFunc(foo)`